# How to get the second or third element DYNAMICALLY of a XML document on XQuery with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

```
declare @X xml='<translations><value lang="en-US">example</value><value lang="1">Beispiel</value></translations>';
declare @Temp int
set @Temp=1
select @X.value('(/translations/value[@lang="'''+@Temp+'''"])[1]','varchar(max)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sql:variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) (or `sql:column` if you're embedding this in a query):

```
declare @Temp int
set @Temp=1
select @X.value('(/translations/value[@lang=sql:variable("@Temp")])[1]','varchar(max)');
```

```
Beispiel
```